# How to setup dependencies for poetry and poetry.lock file if I am working with my own pypi repository(local)?

Tags: python, docker, pip, pypi, python-poetry

My team has a local pypi repository. Developers update all libraries in this repository. My problem is that if someone updates the library included in the dependency of my libraries, then most likely my project will not start.

Tell me, please, how to make your life easier - to auto-check the necessary dependencies for poetry?

**My scenario was broken when somebody puts down the new library in my local pypi-server**. As example, in application indicated asyncpg = { version = "^0.21.0"}, but in folder of local pypi-server have asyncpg=="0.28.0" (
asyncpg-0.28.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl). It's call several problem. Firstly only for amd64 in Linux not working. Secondly there are no secondary dependencies for this library if I want install on windows

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what is going wrong in this scenario? Someone publishing an update to the local repo shouldn't affect your project unless 1) your project specified it's dependencies incorrect or 2) the published package specifies it's version incorrectly. Could you provide a [mre] of the process that's not working currently?